# Can the souls of evil humans/jinn become Shayatin

Tags: islamic-philosophy, shaitan, jahannam, mythology

Surah 6:112 speaks about “shayatin among humans and jinn”. I read there is a division of opinions regarding this verse. One side states, these are children of Iblis, who whisper into the mind of humans and jinn, the other side states, they are jinn and humans who became shayatin themselves.

Is it possible for a wicked soul to become a shayatin, or are they purely the offspring of demons?

Answer (score 1):

A wicked human soul is imprisoned and punished (torment of the grave) after death, it can not return to this world to do anything, and it displays regret rather than becoming defiant.

> حتى إذا جاء أحدهم الموت قال رب ارجعون لعلي أعمل صالحا فيما تركت كلا إنها كلمة هو قائلها ومن ورائهم برزخ إلى يوم يبعثون
>
> Until, when death comes to one of them, he says, "My Lord, send me back that I might do righteousness in that which I left behind."
>
> No! It is only a word he is saying; and behind them is a barrier until the Day they are resurrected.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 23:99-100](https://quran.com/23/99-100?translations=20)</sup>

A human shaitan means a (living) human whose *behavior* is like that of a shaitan.

> والشيطان في كلام العرب، كل متمرد من الجن والإنس والدواب وكل شيء
>
> And shaitan in the language of the Arabs means every rebellious one among the jinn, humans, animals and everything else
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Tabary](https://shamela.ws/book/7798/174)</sup>

> وكل من صد عن سبيل الله وأطيع في معصية الله فهو شيطان
>
> Everyone who averts others from the path of Allah and is obeyed in disobedience to Allah is a shaitan
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://shamela.ws/book/20855/4840) , [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://shamela.ws/book/41/2204)</sup>