# How are devils created?

Tags: shaitan, jinn

How do demons/devils in Islamic traditions come to be? How do they come into being, reproduction etc. I know that God wasn't the one to create them originally, as God only created angels, djinn, and humans originally.

According to this entry, the Five Sons of Iblis reproduce by laying eggs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_five_children_of_Iblis

Answer (score 1):

As explained in your [previous](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77921/) question: Devil simply means a rebellious person. They are not a separate species. When used unqualified 'devils' means the devils among the jinn - or the disbelievers among them. The jinn are created from fire:

> والجان خلقناه من قبل من نار السموم
>
> And the jinn We created before from scorching fire.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 15:27](https://quran.com/15/27?translations=20)</sup>

> فسجدوا إلا إبليس كان من الجن
>
> They prostrated, except for Iblees. He was of the jinn
>
> <sup>— [Quran 18:50](https://quran.com/18/50?translations=20)</sup>

> قال ما منعك ألا تسجد إذ أمرتك قال أنا خير منه خلقتني من نار وخلقته من طين
>
> [Allah] said, "What prevented you from prostrating when I commanded you?" [Satan] said, "I am better than him. You created me from fire and created him from clay."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:12](https://quran.com/7/12?translations=20)</sup>

The relationship between Iblees and the other jinn (including the devils) is not known from any authoritative source. Some claim that he is simply one individual of the species. Many scholars hold that he is the ancestor of all jinn. There are different claims on how he reproduces. Some guess that he has spouses. Others claim that he mates with himself and lays eggs.

---

**Ref:**

> فقد اختلف في أصلهم فقيل إن أصلهم من ولد إبليس فمن كان منهم كافرا سمي شيطانا وقيل إن الشياطين خاصة أولاد إبليس ومن عداهم ليسوا من ولده وحديث بن عباس الآتي في تفسير سورة الجن يقوي أنهم نوع واحد من أصل واحد واختلف صنفه فمن كان كافرا سمي شيطانا وإلا قيل له جني
>
> There is difference on the origin of the Jinn. It has been said that their origin is that they are the children of Iblees, and one who is a disbeliever among them is called a devil. And it has been said that the devils are specifically the children of Iblees and that the jinn other than the devils are not his children.
>
> The [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4921) of Ibn Abbas strengthens the fact that Jinn and devils are one species from a single origin, and that they are different sub-categories, so one who is a disbeliever is called a devil and otherwise is called a Jinn
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/3538#p1)</sup>

Also see [Tafsirs](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura18-aya50.html) of [18:50](https://quran.com/18/50?translations=20) which can be interpreted to mean that that some \ most devils are descendants of Iblees. Iblees himself is from the race of jinn so if the other devils are children of Iblis then logically they too would be of the species of Jinn.

Comment: according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaitan, Shaitan are a separate race as well as a term used to describe wicked people. Your answer has confused me more since you say its just a term, but then say "including the devils" as in the race of evil spirits. 

Maybe your beliefs are not of the mainstream popular one, but from my research so far, Shaitan, or devils are believed to be a separate race.

Comment: @Orionixe I don't know what you find confusing about it, "including the devils" means "including the wicked jinn". I disagree with your impression that devils are believed to be separate race, that would be at best a marginal view. I don't trust wikipedia, as more than once I have seen articles there exaggerating marginal views or making claims in the articles that are not supported by the actual citations. [Britanica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/shaitan) at least confirms what I have written.

Comment: So Shaitan are a sub-class of Djinn, or a subtype then like Ifrit, Jann, etc. If they are a sub-class of Djinn, Shaitan indeed can reproduce correct?